# GTM - Triggers for a Tile Click on a page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, eventtrigger

Trying to set up a trigger in GTM for "5 things partners need to" and had issues looking for the trigger value to be used in GTM. Do you guys have any idea which triggers should I use? (see screenshot below) TIA!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Just Links` trigger with `Click ID` (Built-In Variable) equals *link-65*.